# Consultar 3 tabelas utilizando LINQ e retornar um objeto Json

Tags: json, linq, get

Como faço uma consulta no banco de dados entre 3 tabelas utilizando LINQ retornando um objeto JSON seguindo a Estrutura abaixo ?

```
Public class PedidoGrupo{

    int id ;
    string nome ;
    public virtual List<Pedido> pedidos ;

}

    Public class Pedido{

    int id ;
    int id_PedidoGrupo;
    string destino;
    public virtual List<Pedido> ItensPedidos ;

}

    Public class PedidoItem{

    int id ;
    int id_Pedido;
    string produto;
    string marca;
    string modelo;


}


{  "id": 1,
"Nome": "Rafael",
"pedidos": [{"id":1
            "Destino":"SaoPaulo"
            "ItensPedidos": [{"Produto":"celular",
                             "marca":"Apple",
                             "modelo":"Iphone7"
            }
         ]
    }
```

ou seja, vou comparando os id's semelhantes e quero retornar um array de objetos dentro de PedidosItens que está dentro de pedidos, que por sua vez esta dentro de PedidosGrupo.

Qual a maneira correta de se fazer isso ? Estou com difculdade.

Comment: Como esta o contexto da sua aplicação? Esta usando CodeFirst? DBFirst?

Comment: Modelo Code First

Comment: Já tentou utilizar includes no LINQ?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx